# Why "What's up"?

Tags: etymology

Why's "what's up" used as greeting among young people? It sounds like asking "what is up there"?

> A: What's up?
>
> B: The sky.

Comment: What's going down? Just idioms. What's up was popularised by Bugs Bunny and again as wazzup from a beer commercial so not just among young people

Comment: @mplungjan: Still, every idiom has some origin and knowing origin of this one would be interesting. My guess: it's directly related to "What's the top news?"

Comment: Sure - see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Up* has many, many uses and referring to something that is above is just one of them.

*What’s up* is not an innovation by the young of today. As a statement or a question about what might be happening, it isn't particularly new. In a letter written in 1838, the novelist Elizabeth Gaskell wrote *I did not mention a word to Lucy but she must have guessed something was ‘up’.* Even in its reduced form of *wassup*, it’s over 100 years old.

Comment: Absolutely. I think it's a trivial extension from [What are you up to?](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22what+are+you+up+to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=iaj-UIegE8yR0QWJuoHoDA&ved=0CCgQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1700%2Ccd_max%3A1%2F1%2F1825&tbm=bks) and [{he is} up to no good](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22up+to+no+good%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6aj-UKisKuuz0QXY_YDQDA&ved=0CCgQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1700%2Ccd_max%3A1%2F1%2F1825&tbm=bks), both of which occur well before even your citation.

Answer (score 1):

Just another idiom

[What's up or wazzup](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/what%27s_up)

> **Etymology**
> Made popular by the cartoon character Bugs Bunny who used it
> as early as 1940 as part of his catch phrase “What’s up Doc?” (where
> each word was pronounced distinctly).
>
> **Alternative forms**
> wassup, what up, waz up, wazzup, whassup, wuzzup, wussup, sup, wa'up, swa'up,
> what's good

[Bugs Bunny](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pwLn_His9Yw&noredirect=1)

[Budweiser commercial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tauYnVE6ykU)